# Migrate comments and likes wordpress.com to selfhosted site

Tags: comments, migration, wordpress.com-hosting

I have recently changed from wordpress.com to wordpress.org, all content has transferred over completely fine (posts etc) and I have the theme/design set up the way I'd like now.

I also found a way to migrate followers from my wordpress.com to my self hosted site, and I think that's worked now.

However, my final problem is - is there a way to transfer all my old comments and likes from my wordpress.com site to my new selfhosted one?

All my old comments etc are still linked to my old site and I'd like to have them all in one place on my new one, is this possible?

Comment: Not sure I understand which comments and likes you are talking about, but you should just ask wordpress.com support

Comment: You should contact WP.com support, they will know how to wrangle this